# Grep: find lines only matching unknown character once

Tags: regex, grep

I have a list with hexadecimal lines. For example:

```
0b 5a 3f 5a 7d d0 5d e6 2b c4 7e 7d c2 c0 e6 9a 
84 bd aa 74 f3 85 da 9d ac b6 e0 b6 62 0f b5 d5
c0 b0 f5 60 02 8b 1c a4 41 7c 53 f2 85 20 a0 d1
...
```

I'm trying to find all the lines with grep, where there is a character that occurs only once in the line.

For example: there is only one time a 'd' in the third line.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
egrep '^.*([a-f0-9])[^\1]*$'
```

Comment: You mean all the lines where any character occurs only once? Or where a particular character occurs only once? If it's the latter, you could use egrep '^[^d]*d[^d]*$'to get all the lines with only one d.

Comment: All the lines where any character occurs only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a regex, but it has to be verbose.
It kind of can't be generalized.

```
 # ^(?:[^a]*a[^a]*|[^b]*b[^b]*|[^c]*c[^c]*|[^d]*d[^d]*|[^e]*e[^e]*|[^f]*f[^f]*|[^0]*0[^0]*|[^1]*1[^1]*|[^2]*2[^2]*|[^3]*3[^3]*|[^4]*4[^4]*|[^5]*5[^5]*|[^6]*6[^6]*|[^7]*7[^7]*|[^8]*8[^8]*|[^9]*9[^9]*)$

 ^ 
 (?:
      [^a]* a [^a]* 
   |  [^b]* b [^b]* 
   |  [^c]* c [^c]* 
   |  [^d]* d [^d]* 
   |  [^e]* e [^e]* 
   |  [^f]* f [^f]* 

   |  [^0]* 0 [^0]* 
   |  [^1]* 1 [^1]* 
   |  [^2]* 2 [^2]* 
   |  [^3]* 3 [^3]* 
   |  [^4]* 4 [^4]* 
   |  [^5]* 5 [^5]* 
   |  [^6]* 6 [^6]* 
   |  [^7]* 7 [^7]* 
   |  [^8]* 8 [^8]* 
   |  [^9]* 9 [^9]* 
 )
 $
```

For discovery, if you put capture groups around the letters and numbers,
and use a brach reset:

```
 ^ 
 (?|
      [^a]* (a) [^a]* 
   |  [^b]* (b) [^b]* 
   |  [^c]* (c) [^c]* 
   |  [^d]* (d) [^d]* 
   |  [^e]* (e) [^e]* 
   |  [^f]* (f) [^f]* 

   |  [^0]* (0) [^0]* 
   |  [^1]* (1) [^1]* 
   |  [^2]* (2) [^2]* 
   |  [^3]* (3) [^3]* 
   |  [^4]* (4) [^4]* 
   |  [^5]* (5) [^5]* 
   |  [^6]* (6) [^6]* 
   |  [^7]* (7) [^7]* 
   |  [^8]* (8) [^8]* 
   |  [^9]* (9) [^9]* 
 )
 $
```

This is the output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 50 ) 
0b 5a 3f 5a 7d d0 5d e6 2b c4 7e 7d c2 c0 e6 9a 

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 7 , len 1 ) 
f  

-----------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 50 , len 51 ) 

84 bd aa 74 f3 85 da 9d ac b6 e0 b6 62 0f b5 d5

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 77 , len 1 ) 
c  

-----------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 101 , len 51 ) 

c0 b0 f5 60 02 8b 1c a4 41 7c 53 f2 85 20 a0 d1

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 148 , len 1 ) 
d
```

Comment: I think this solution is not practicable. I'm from Germany, what's with the `ß` ? I mean this solution will not work for most text input data in the world,however it will work for mac-addresses ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl - Not really practical except in a limited verbose way. It is what it is.

Comment: I thought about this again... I would say the answer to the general question: "All the lines where any character occurs only once." is solvable only if the character set is limited to something processable by a regex (I don't know the limits of the pattern length but I guess there is some limit). Meaning this will being likely impossible for unicode. However, your answer shows that it is indeed possible having a limited set of characters, especially for mac addresses as input data. finally a good answer imo +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do it with a regex. However you can use this stupid `awk` script:

```
awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[$i]++};for(i in a){if(a[i]==1){print;next}}}' input
```

The scripts counts the number of occurrences of every character in the line. At the end of the line it checks all totals and prints the line if at least one of those totals equals `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that uses a number of shell tools beyond `grep`.
It reads the input line by line. Generates a frequency table. Upon finding an element with frequency 1 it outputs the unique character and the entire line.

```
cat input | while read line ; do 
     export line ; 
     echo $line | grep -o . | sort | uniq -c | \
         awk '/[ ]+1[ ]/ {print $2 ":" ENVIRON["line"] ; exit }' ; 
done
```

Note that if you are interested in digits only you could replace `grep -o .` with `grep -o "[a-f]"`